# How to filter a textfield based on special characters like ().+* in ExtJS using the keyup listener

Tags: extjs

I had a requirement to filter the `textfield` based on input characters, its working fine when we give normal characters, but when we enter special characters its not filtering.

How can I filter a `textfield` based on special characters like ().+* in ExtJS using the `keyup` listener?

***Note: remaining special characters are working fine, only ().+ * are not working

**Code:**

```
var filter = function (valu, listv) {
    if (valu !== '') {
        listv.store.filter({
            property     : 'value',
            value        : new RegExp(valu, "i"),
            anyMatch     : true, //optional, defaults to true
            caseSensitive: true  //optional, defaults to true
        });
    } else {
        listv.store.filter({
            property     : 'value',
            value        : /.*/,
            anyMatch     : true,
            caseSensitive: true
        });
    }
    listv.select(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) the special characters in the RegEx like so:

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

var filter = function (valu, listv) {
    if (valu !== '') {
        listv.store.filter({
            property     : 'value',
            value        : new RegExp(escapeRegExp(valu), "i"),
// ...
```

Comment: Hi @Pumbaa80 my regex: /^[a-zA-Z0-9àçéèêîïôù\-.,:+*'()=&_\s]+$/ can you please tell me how to esape the ().+ * characters so that my search criteria will work fine

Comment: You don't need to double-escape inside RegExp literals, only when using the constructor function. I edited my answer and added some code

Comment: Hi  @Pumbaa80,@Chau i tried escaping the specail characters in my Regex, but its not working.I have a search field where i have to search a field based on the special characters .+*() which is not working.other special characters are working fine like ,-_&', please suggest me acorrect solution

Comment: Hi @Pumbaa80 its not working with the piece of code you gave i dont know the reason why??? iwill explain you clearly please see: I have a filter text field where we can search the list of values based on the regex criteria we provide and should display the values matched

Comment: I think you better ask this in the ExtJS forums. The question is not specific enough for StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi @Pumbaa80, its working fine now, i cleaned my server and restarted..thanks a lot for the solution